# How many physical tiers exist in real world applications

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture

I'm looking for an answer from those who have experience with complex real world enterprise n-tier applications.

How many physical tiers (distributed to separate machines) exist in practice in enterprise apps beyond the obvious 3?

What technlogies are mostly used for inter-tier communication, both in Java EE and .NET worlds?

Are there (m)any DCOM-based n-tier apps?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer to your questions.
I can put 3 tier on 2 servers, 1 server, 3 servers.

Every Tier can be divided logically to more tiers...
database can be divided to Actual database, Data access layer, ORM, you can theoretically put each layer into a single machine but it will be inefficient.

SO - the answer to your question - is as many as you like.
I consider performance and security in the decision to separate, some will also consider complexity.

I use ORM like nHibernate from App tier to DB and WCF from the presentation tier to the App tier. (in the .NET world).

(there might be dcom based n-tier apps, but this technology is old and I wouldn't use it in new projects)

Comment: you're saying Tiers, but don't you really mean Layers? Tiers are physical, Layers are logical. Granted ORM, WCF, etc exist as physically different code, but I thought a Tier implied a server boundary?  (not arguing, just trying to understand).

Answer (score 0):

For the current project I'm working on ther is

- The GUI tier
- The server tier
- The DB tier
- The slave tier

The slave tier is a tier consisting of slave computers carrying out offline batch processes. The slaves sole responsivbility is to carry out massively parallel computations-

Our software architecture, however, is separated into only three tiers: gui, server, and the data shared by gui and server.